# Declension of the word "water" (maim) in Hebrew?

Tags: nouns, hebrew, conjugation, ancient

What is the conjugated (that is used in smikhut) form of the word "maim" (water)? Is it "maim" or "mai"? (I'm asking about ancient biblical Hebrew, but I am almost sure it is the same as in modern Hebrew.)

Comment: For "conjugated" read "construct".

Comment: In the modern Hebrew it's only "mei", for example as the name of organizations: http://www.mei-rg.co.il/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Van der Merve, Naudé and Kroeze (*A Biblical Hebrew Reference Grammar*) give the incomprehensible מֵימֵיוֹמֵי as the construct for מַיִם; but looking at other entries in the table, I believe this is meant to say מֵימֵי וֹ מֵי, i.e. "meymey or mey"

Comment: Good point, I'd forgotten about the less common form מֵימֵי; adding it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The form is *mey* מֵי, e.g. *mey-hayam* "the water of the sea".

ETA: As Colin Fine mentions below, there is also a longer alternate form *meymey* מֵימֵי.